# Symfony Form - query builder passing values from fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I am using two EntityType types fields. The data in the second field is depending on the choice in the first field. And the data from the third field is depending on the choice in second field. How can I do this form dynamic and pass selection value from the first field to the second? For now I come up with this:

```
->add('country', EntityType::class, [
'class'         => 'AppBundle:Country',
'choice_label'  => 'name',
'label'         => 'Country',
'data'          => $countryId //this is wrong, i know. here i must somehow save the choice and pass it into next field
])
->add('state', EntityType::class, [
'class'         => 'AppBundle:State',
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($countryId) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->where('s.country =:country_id')
        ->setParameter('country_id', $countryId)
        ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
},
'choice_label'  => 'name',
'label'         => 'State',
'data'          => $stateId //this is wrong, i know. here i must somehow save the choice and pass it into next field
])
->add('city', EntityType::class, [
'class'         => 'AppBundle:City',
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($stateId) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.state =:state_id')
        ->setParameter('state_id', $stateId)
        ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
},
'choice_label'  => 'name',
'label'         => 'City'  
])
```

I use the documentation and I come to this code. I get the error: "You cannot add children to a simple form. Maybe you should set the option "compound" to true?". I try to owerride the getParent method with return 'trigger' but it could not load the class. How can i oweride it correctly?

```
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, PowerPlant $power_plant = null) {
        $devices = null === $power_plant ? array() : $power_plant->getDevices();
        $form->add('device', EntityType::class, [
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:Device',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices'     => $devices,
            'label'       => 'Device',
        ]);
    };

->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($form = $event->getForm(), $power_plant = $data->getPowerPlant());
            }
        )
        ->get('power_plant')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $power_plant = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $power_plant);
            }
        )
```

In my template i added the JS:

```
<script>
var $power_plant = $('#trigger_power_plant');
$power_plant.change(function() {
var $form = $(this).closest('form');
var data = {};
data[$power_plant.attr('name')] = $power_plant.val();
$.ajax({
url : $form.attr('action'),
type: $form.attr('method'),
data : data,
success: function(html) {
  $('#trigger_device').replaceWith(
    $(html).find('#trigger_device')
  );
}
});
});
```

Comment: For this you'll need form events: [*"Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms"*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms). You should try to implement the ideas explained by the docs, and if you get stuck update your (or write a new) question.

Comment: You might find useful this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815712/validate-a-dynamically-populated-choice-field/27988459#27988459. The problem described there is similar, check my answer.